# Port Address Translation via Local Desktop

Tags: networking, proxy, testing, pat

Recommendations for how I might configure Windows and Macs to perform port address translation locally.

Need to test a web service that sits on port 99. The client application I am testing (think device simulator) will not allow me to hit a port, it automatically assumes port 80.  In production, we have a gateway that would perform a translation between incoming port 80 to port 99 on the web server.  I'm looking for something no-frills to do the job locally on the client box, without having to installing squid or other firewall/proxy service elsewhere.

Comment: The web service's port can't change?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a reverse proxy. Apache can do it, as can IIS (but Apache's is better). There are dozens of questions on this site about how to set it up. [You can find some of them here](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy).

You will then point your simulator to `:80` and it will then proxy your request to `wherever:99`